# How to change getter signature generated by Qt Creator for Q_PROPERTY?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

If I start typing `Q_PROPERTY` in a header file, Qt Creator offers to complete the code with a snippet:

[image]

My issue is with the default getter name. My company's coding style requires "get" prefixing getter methods. I want the getter in the snippet to be `getName`, not `name`. And no, finding another job is *not* an option.

I was sure I was on to a solution when I found `QtCreator\share\qtcreator\snippets\cpp.xml` and modified the line:

```
<snippet group="C++" trigger="Q_PROPERTY" id="cpp_q_property">Q_PROPERTY($type$ $name$ READ $name$ WRITE set$name:c$ NOTIFY $name$Changed)</snippet>
```

to use `READ get$name:c$` ... but it doesn't change anything. Is there a way to get Qt Creator to use the cpp.xml file?

Is there any way to change the generated getter name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the QtCreator **Tools/Options/Text Editor/Snippets** menu option to edit the Q_PROPERTY triggered snippet and tailor the auto-completion code to produce the desired getter name.

The working snippet reads:
Q_PROPERTY($type$ $name$ READ get$name:c$ WRITE set$name:c$ NOTIFY $name$Changed)

Answer (score 1):

The way I come around this is I type Q_PROPERTY and pick my variable name. I accept the default function names. The process completes when I type `;` at the end line.

Now I can change any function name, for example `getName`for `name` as getter . Note if you change the name before you type `;` at the end of line, it will change other functions name as well, so you want to accept the default by ending line with `;` first.

Once you have tweaked the function names, right click on Q_PROPERTY word and from `Refactor` menu select `generate missing Q_PROPERTY members` and it will generate the correct names as listed in the line.

Comment: Back when I could use Qt style, I'd type Q_PRO, Alt+Space, Enter, "int", Tab, "count", Enter. That's in muscle memory (well, int count was an example -- I don't generate count properties all day). That was efficient and having to modify the getter increases the time and risk of a typo.